# BarButtonItem Issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I have issue with my BarButtonItem in TableView after Navigation Controller. Everything is done using storyboard. The icon looks differently in Storyboard and on iOS device (simulator and real device).

Storyboard:

[image]

iOS device:

[image]

The sizes of the asset are 28x32 for 1x, 56x64 for 2x and 84x96 for 3x

Comment: can you share code ?

Comment: There is no code related to this. Everything is done using storyboard